# Parse csv file with commas and quotes‬‏

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

This was asked before but no solution worked for me.

I have a csv file that looks like that:

```
data1,data2,data3,"<tag field1=""test"" field2=""test,2,3""></tag>",data4
```

When I split by comma it doesn't fit because of the data in the tag, so I want to use regex or something to ignore every time I see a "".

I am using winforms, and I want to extract from the csv only the data1,data2 etc.

any ideas please?

thank you

*EDIT:* I would be more precise: it shouldn't be a hard task because I know that I want to ignore whatever inside the "tag" so the regex can do that no?
in the example above I want to use the regex and manipulate the line to give me the following result:

```
data1,data2,data3,data4
```

is it clear now? thank you all

Comment: If you want simple string splitting make sure you *don't* need to escape, eg ensure that `'` is used instead of `"` inside the text. CSV is supposed to be a simple and fast format. Otherwise look for a CSV parser that handles escaping. [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/3.0.0-beta6) is the most popular NuGet package but there are others

Comment: @panagiotisKanavos I am using a large file of a CSV foramt, that I can't ensure that doesn't have  `'`.  and I also don't want to use an existing library, I want to make something flexible and small for my needs.

Comment: Small and fast means ensuring the creator of the file doesn't have to use escaping. Export utilities allow you to define row and field separators, so you could use characters that won't appear in normal text, eg § or ¤. Otherwise you need to use a library that *already* does what you want. What you call "flexible" requires handling a lot of different cases, so it can't be "small". You can't use a single Regex to parse that. Am I right in guessing that there may be newlines in the text fields?

Comment: Besides, libraries typically don't use string splitting. They parse characters as they appear in the input stream, resulting in better performance and memory utilization

Answer (score 1):

There are several open source CSV parsers available as NuGet packages which will handle all of this for you. Your best bet is to use one of those, as there's no need to write parsers for common file formats on popular platforms because there's probably already at least one which will do what you want.

If you really want to parse this yourself, which I wouldn't recommend unless you're really interested in parsing or you need some very exotic requirement nothing else will satisfy, you're going to need something more capable than a simple regular expression. Regexes aren't good at handling the quoted fields, and you also have to bear in mind that quoted fields can have newlines in them as per the RFC.

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, to be more specific about the regex part

Comment: Your initial question was about parsing CSV in general, which is quite hard. Still, even with your change it's still not going to be easy to accurately identify that particular quoted field and ignore it. While parsing is often easier when you have more information about the input file than just "it's a CSV", I'd still suggest that a proper CSV parser is your best option here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library as you comment, you can do something like this for single line data (pseudo code):

```
read a line

bool bInsideQuotes = false

loop over chars
  if character == '"'
    bInsideQuotes = !bInsideQuotes
  if character == ',' and !bInsideQuotes
    found a field separator
```

Or instead of reading line by line you could read over the whole file and process the newlines yourself (only if `!bInsideQuotes`, which allows for multiline rows).

Comment: thank you but this method won't work if I will have multiple quoetes one after another or for uneven qouets. it may work if I set the prefix to "<tag" and the suffix to "</tag>",  but I guess it uses regex and this is my problem. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @TheDaJon If your csv data is properly escaped this should always work. Every quote inside a field is escaped with another quote, so they are always even.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity I spent the better part of the day trying to write my own CSV parser that would handle any variant of commas and quotes entered in the CSV field values. This is what I came up with (requires string $myfilename and boolean $use_headers as inputs)

```
<?php
$rows = file($myfilename)
for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++)
{
    # Remove non-printable characters
    $rows[$i] = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $rows[$i]);

    # Reduce csv line to only commas and quotes
    $cleanup_1 = preg_replace('/[^,"]/', '', $rows[$i]);

    # Count the number of quote characters between commas.
    # When the cumulative number of quotes is an even number,
    # you have a distinct field from your CSV line data.
    # Record the key valus for delimiter commas.
    $delimiters = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach(explode(',', $cleanup_1) as $key => $value)
    {
        $count += strlen($value);
        if($count % 2 == 0)
        {
            $delimiters[] = $key;
            $count = 0;
        }
    }

    # Split your original line data by commas and combine
    # text values between delimiters.
    $strings = array();
    $new_array = array();
    foreach(explode(',', $rows[$i]) as $key => $value)
    {
        $strings[] = $value;
        if(in_array($key, $delimiters))
        {
            $text = implode(',', $strings);
            # If the field value contains escaped commas or quotes, 
            # remove the beginning and end quotation marks. 
            if(substr($text, 0, 1) == '"' && substr($text, strlen($text)-1, 1) == '"')
            {
                $text = substr($text, 1, strlen($text)-2);
                $text = str_replace('""', '"', $text);
            }
            $new_array[] = $text;
            $strings = array();
        }
    }

    # Optional setting to include headers. $user_headers
    # will be a boolean input. Result is a set of 
    # associative arrays with matching, aligned keys.
    if($i == 0 && $use_headers)
    {
        $headers = array();
        foreach($new_array as $key => $header)
            {$headers[$key] = $header;}
    } else {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach($new_array as $key => $value)
        {
            if($use_headers)
                {$tmp[$headers[$key]] = $value;} 
            else
                {$tmp[] = $value;}
        }
        $data_array[] = $tmp;
    }
}
?>
```